# Add field to documents after $sort aggregation pipeline which include its index in sorted list using MongoDb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get the order of some user from a list after `$sort` aggregation pipeline.

Let's say we have a leaderboard, and I need to get **my rank in the leaderboard with only one query getting only my data**.

I have tried `$addFields` and some queries with `$map`

Let's say we have these documents

```js
/* 1 createdAt:8/18/2019, 4:42:41 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5963e1c6c93b2da849f067"),
    "name" : "x4",
    "points" : 69
},

/* 2 createdAt:8/18/2019, 4:42:41 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5963e1c6c93b2da849f07b"),
    "name" : "x24",
    "points" : 968
},

/* 3 createdAt:8/18/2019, 4:42:41 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5963e1c6c93b2da849f06a"),
    "name" : "x7",
    "points" : 997
},
```

And I want to write a query like this

```js
db.table.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort : { points : 1 } },
     { $addFields: { order : "$index" } },
     { $match : { name : "x24" } }
   ]
)
```

I need to inject the `order` field with something like `$index`

I expect to have something like this in return

```js
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5d5963e1c6c93b2da849f07b"),
   "name" : "x24",
   "points" : 968,
   "order" : 2
}
```

**I need something like the metadata of the result here which return 2**

`/* 2 createdAt:8/18/2019, 4:42:41 PM*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the workaround for this situation is to convert your all documents into one single array and hence resolve the index of the document using this array with help of `$unwind` and finally project the data with fields as required.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { points: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      register: { $push: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name", points: "$points" } }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$register", includeArrayIndex: "order" } },
  { $match: { "register.name": "x4" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$register._id",
      name: "$register.name",
      points: "$register.points",
      order: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

To make it more efficient you can apply limit, match, and filter as per your requirement.

Comment: After a lot of digging, I think this the best answer till now, I will try it tomorrow and try to enhance its performance and let you know  

Comment: Thanks @milanregmi  